# Custom header problem with LWC

Tags: apex, custom-object, custom-field, header

I want to create a custom header with my custom field, but with this code, I can't see the fields, they are not visible, what is the error in my code ?

```
<template>
    <div class="myheader slds-page-header">
        <div class="slds-page-header__row">
         
            <div>
                <lightning-input-field field-name="Statut__c"> </lightning-input-field>
                <lightning-input-field field-name="Name"> </lightning-input-field>
                <lightning-input-field field-name="Profit_Center_Formula__c"> </lightning-input-field>
                <lightning-input-field field-name="Station_Type__c"> </lightning-input-field>                  
    </div>

</div>
</div>

</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

`lightning-input-field` must be inside a `lightning-record-edit-form` in order to be visible.

Comment: thanks , i added a lightning-record-edit-form and it worked , thanks